# Can WSGI's Upper Portion be used as an alternative to MemCache to Cache MySQL outputs?

Tags: python, python-2.7, memcached, mod-wsgi, wsgi

In WSGI everything above this line is cached in 8 different threads.

```
 def application(environ, start_response):
```

should i go with MemCached for caching MySQL outputs

or should i think of a way to use WSGI for caching the MySQL output

can it even be done ?

would this be the wrong way to do things ?

Answer (score 0):

No, everything above that line is not cached in 8 different threads.

What is more likely happening is that you are using mod_wsgi in a multi process configuration and so you have 8 separate copies of your application, each in a different independent process.

If you truly had a multithreaded process, then all threads would be accessing the same global objects within the WSGI script file/module.

You need to provide more information about your specific Apache/mod_wsgi configuration to even begin to understand why you are seeing what you do.

You should at least read:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading

You also should perhaps consider using mod_wsgi daemon mode with a single multithread processes. But then in doing that, you then have to contend with the problems around multithreaded applications accessing shared data. That is, you would need to ensure access to global data is protected by appropriate thread locks. In the case of database connections, you need to use a database connection pooling mechanism or otherwise ensure that each thread is using its own database connection anyway.